# Symfony2 Authenticating Someone with a Custom Entity Provider ERROR

Tags: php, symfony, user-management

I faced a problem when trying to implement the **Custom Entity Provider** for user authentication. I got the Mapping Exception that my entity is not a valid or mapped super class. Here is my Actual Error:
    **------------- Exception/Error Start --------------**

```
1/1 MappingException: Class MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\UmUsers is not a valid entity or mapped super class.

in C:\wamp\www\idp\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException.php line 142
at MappingException::classIsNotAValidEntityOrMappedSuperClass() in C:\wamp\www\idp\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DriverChain.php line 80
at DriverChain->loadMetadataForClass() in C:\wamp\www\idp\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php line 281
at ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() in C:\wamp\www\idp\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php line 170
at ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() in C:\wamp\www\idp\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php line 257
at EntityManager->getClassMetadata() in C:\wamp\www\idp\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php line 573
at EntityManager->getRepository() in C:\wamp\www\idp\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider.php line 42
at EntityUserProvider->__construct() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 2191
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_User_Provider_Concrete_UserDbService() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 190
at Container->get() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 2174
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_User_Provider_Concrete_ChainProviderService() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 190
at Container->get() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 2140
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_Authentication_ManagerService() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 190
at Container->get() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1304
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_ContextService() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 190
at Container->get() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1178
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getProfilerService() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 190
at Container->get() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1195
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getProfilerListenerService() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 190
at Container->get() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 4779
at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->lazyLoad() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 4768
at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 3916
at HttpKernel->handleException() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 3855
at HttpKernel->handle() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 4828
at HttpKernel->handle() in C:\wamp\www\idp\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 547
at Kernel->handle() in C:\wamp\www\idp\web\app_dev.php line 20

**------------- Exception/Error End --------------**
```

Lets describe my application

1. I have three databases **DB-A**, **DB-B**, **DB-C** and make three database connections in **config.yml** file which are **default**: DB-A, **DB_B**: DB-B, **DB_C**: DB-C
2. **default** connection is configured with **default_entity_manager** ORM, other entity managers **DB_B**  uses connection DB_B and mapping with MIGPatBundle, **DB_C** uses connection DB_C and also mapping with MIGPatBundle.
3. My **UmUsers** entity resides in MIGPatBundle and we need to validate it in **DB-B** database.
4. I explain these elaborately because if i change the **default_entity_manager** ORM from **default** to **DB_B** then it works fine.

Here is my files

------------- config.yml Start --------------

```
**Doctrine Configuration**

doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection:       default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   "%db_driver_DB-A%"
            host:     "%db_host_DB-A%"
            port:     "%db_port_DB-A%"
            dbname:   "%db_name_DB-A%"
            user:     "%db_user_DB-A%"
            password: "%db_password_DB-A%"
            charset:  UTF8
        DB_B:
            driver:   "%db_driver_DB-B%"
            host:     "%db_host_DB-B%"
            port:     "%db_port_DB-B%"
            dbname:   "%db_name_DB-B%"
            user:     "%db_user_DB-B%"
            password: "%db_password_DB-B%"
            charset:  UTF8
        DB_C:
            driver:   "%db_driver_DB-C%"
            host:     "%db_host_DB-C%"
            port:     "%db_port_DB-C%"
            dbname:   "%db_name_DB-C%"
            user:     "%db_user_DB-C%"
            password: "%db_password_DB-C%"
            charset:  UTF8

orm:
    default_entity_manager:   default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection:       default
            mappings:
                MIGBundle: ~
        DB_B:
            connection:       DB_B
            mappings:
                MIGPatBundle: ~
        DB_C:
            connection:       DB_C
            mappings:
                MIGPatBundle: ~
```

------------- config.yml End --------------

------------- security.yml Start ------------

```
security:
encoders:
    MIG\PatBundle\Entity\UmUsers:
        algorithm: sha512
        encode-as-base64: true
        iterations: 10

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    chain_provider:
        providers: [user_db]
    user_db:
        entity: { class: MIG\PatBundle\Entity\UmUsers }

firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        logout:
            target: /
        form_login:
            provider: chain_provider
            check_path:  /security/login_check
            default_target_path: /
            login_path:  /security/login

access_control:
    - { path: ^/account, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/management, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/portfolio, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/portfoliogroup, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/security, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/userpatent, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/_internal, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }

access_denied_url: /security/forbidden
```

------------- security.yml End --------------

------------- User Entity Start --------------

```
<?php

namespace MIG\PatBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 *MIG\PatBundle\Entity\UmUsers
 *  
 *@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MIG\PatBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 *@ORM\Table(name = "um_users")
 */
class UmUsers implements UserInterface
{

 /**
  @var string $id

  @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", length=36, nullable=false)
  @ORM\Id
  @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_name", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 *
 * @var string $userName
 */
private $userName;

/**
 * @var string $email
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 */
private $email;

    /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 *
 * @Assert\MinLength(
 *     limit = 6,
 *     message = "The password must contain at least {{ limit }} characters."
 * )
 * @var string $password
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var string $salt
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $salt;

/**
 * @var string $activationCode
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="activation_code", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $activationCode;

/**
 * @var boolean $activated
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="activated", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $activated;

/**
 * @var UmRoles
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UmRoles", inversedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="um_usersinroles",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $role;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->role = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    $this->lastLoginAt = new \DateTime();
    $this->lastUpdatedDate = new \DateTime();
    $this->lastLoginDate = new \DateTime();
    $this->lastPasswordChangedDate = new \DateTime();
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set userName
 *
 * @param string $userName
 */
public function setUserName($userName)
{
    $this->userName = $userName;
}

/**
 * Get userName
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getUserName()
{
    return $this->userName;
}

/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

/**
 * Get password
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Set salt
 *
 * @param string $salt
 */
public function setSalt($salt)
{
    $this->salt = $salt;
}

/**
 * Get salt
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSalt()
{
    return $this->salt;
}

/**
 * Set activationCode
 *
 * @param string $activationCode
 */
public function setActivationCode($activationCode)
{
    $this->activationCode = $activationCode;
}

/**
 * Get activationCode
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getActivationCode()
{
    return $this->activationCode;
}

/**
 * Set activated
 *
 * @param boolean $activated
 */
public function setActivated($activated)
{
    $this->activated = $activated;
}

/**
 * Get activated
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getActivated()
{
    return $this->activated;
}

/**
 * Add role
 *
 * @param MIG\PatBundle\Entity\UmRoles $role
 */
public function addUmRoles(\MIG\PatBundle\Entity\UmRoles $role)
{
    $this->role[] = $role;
}

/**
 * Get role
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getRole()
{
    return $this->role;
}



/**
 * Gets an array of roles.
 *
 * @return array An array of Role objects
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->getRole()->toArray();
}

/**
 * Erases the user credentials.
 */
public function eraseCredentials()
{
}


/**
 * Compares this user to another to determine if they are the same.
 *
 * @param UserInterface $user The user
 * @return booleanean True if equal, false othwerwise.
 */
public function equals(UserInterface $user)
{
    return md5($this->getUsername()) == md5($user->getUsername());
}
```

}

------------- User Entity End --------------

------------- UserRepository Entity Start--------------

```
namespace MIG\PatBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;


class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
{
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    $q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.userName = :username OR u.email = :email')
        ->setParameter('username', $username)
        ->setParameter('email', $username)
        ->getQuery()
    ;

    try {
        // The Query::getSingleResult() method throws an exception
        // if there is no record matching the criteria.
        $user = $q->getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException $e) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Unable to find an active admin MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\UmUsers object identified by "%s".', $username), null, 0, $e);
    }

    return $user;
}

public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    $class = get_class($user);
    if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
        throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', $class));
    }

    return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
}

public function supportsClass($class)
{
    return $this->getEntityName() === $class || is_subclass_of($class, $this->getEntityName());
}
}
```

------------- UserRepository Entity End--------------

Actually i have a deadline to complete this task. I will be very much glade to you if someone can give me the solution.

Regards,
Zaif

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/security.xml, you'll see this:

```
<service id="security.user.provider.entity" class="%security.user.provider.entity.class%" abstract="true" public="false"    >
    <argument type="service" id="security.user.entity_manager" />       
</service>
<service id="security.user.entity_manager" alias="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" public="false" />
```

I think you need to override the `security.user.entity_manager` , but I am not sure how (maybe adding some lines in security.yml will do the trick), and since it is not public, I am not sure whether you can.

If this does not work, maybe you could report an issue about this.